# Evaluate the following expression:

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

$$\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n\choose r} \left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^r + \left(\frac{3}{2^2}\right)^r + \left(\frac{7}{2^3}\right)^r + \left(\frac{15}{2^4}\right)^r+ \cdots m\text{-terms}\right]$$

Please provide me with a solution. A hint would do too. Thank you.

Comment: This is some kind of artistic math? xD

Comment: The syntax is `(\frac{1}{2})^r + (\frac{3}{4})^r` to display $(\frac{1}{2})^r + (\frac{3}{4})^r$.  It is not immediately clear to me what the pattern is to fix the typos, and I need to leave at the moment, so I leave that to you to fix, but it appears you are using parenthesis instead of braces in your syntax.

Comment: @JohnJoy ... doesn't look much better after your edit ...

Comment: @Gyro Gearloose I fixed the first term, so that the OP can copy and fix it himself (as per his intent).

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. Well as blatantly obvious it is, i am 'new' with the syntax and this site as a whole. That made it artistic beyond imagination. Haha. Thanks to all.

Comment: @Phill2, have you already attempted anything to solve the question? If so, can you add it to the question?

Comment: The answer is $$\frac{2^{mn}-1}{2^{mn}(2^{n}-1)}$$if you show me your efforts , I'll show you mine.

Comment: Nikunj: can you give me a hint? I've tried but couldn't get any idea to solve the series inside the square braces.

Comment: I suspect the reason why some have down-voted this question is that the first paragraph is phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.  This can lead to suspicions that a question was merely copied by someone who didn't even understanding the question.  I don't think that's what's happening here because the request for a hint is not consistent with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This summation can be broken up and written like:

\begin{align}
& \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^{r}{n\choose r} \left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^r + \left(\frac{3}{2^{2}}\right)^r + \left(\frac{7}{2^3}\right)^r + \left(\frac{15}{2^4}\right)^r+ \cdots\ m\text{-terms}\right] \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n\choose r} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^r+\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n\choose r} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^r + \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^{r}{n\choose r} \left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^r+\cdots \\[10pt]
= & {} \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\left(1-\frac{3}{4}\right)^n+\left(1-\frac{7}{8}\right)^n+\cdots
\end{align}

(Using the fact that $\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {n\choose r}x^{r}=(1-x)^n$)

And you're almost done. (Look for a Geometric progression)

Comment: At first I thought your MathJax skills are as weak as those of the original poster, but on closer inspection, it appeared that you simply copied and pasted from the question.  I've cleaned it up. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes I merely copied the original question,and thanks for the edits Michael! (I'm not good at MathJax)

Comment: @nikunj: Gotcha. I was wasting time to compress all the m terms within the square braces at once. When all i had to do was simply expand the expression. Thank you.